# Infix to Postfix program. EmptyCollectionException

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

//This is the exception that the program throws

The program won´t compile successfully, it throws an EmptyCollectionException.

> Exception in thread "main" EmptyCollectionException: La colección está vacía:
> Stack underflow.
>
> ```
>   at ArrayStack.peek(ArrayStack.java:57)
>   at Convertidor.convierte(Convertidor.java:58)
>   at postfix.main(postfix.java:20)
> ```
>
> Java Result: 1

```
 public class Convertidor {
//This method will calculate the priority of the operators.
        public  int  prioridad(char e){
            int p, prioridad;
            char ch;
            prioridad=0;
            char[] operadores = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/','^' };
            for(p=0;p<operadores.length;p++){
                ch=operadores[p];
                if(p=='+'||p=='-')
                    prioridad=1;
                if(p=='/'||p=='*')
                    prioridad=2;
                if(p=='^')
                    prioridad=3;
            }
            return prioridad;
        }
    
        public  String convierte(String entrada){
            String salida="";
            String resp;
            char e,r,ch;
            String n;
            n="";
            int i, pri,p;
            pri=0;
            StringBuffer buff=new StringBuffer();
            ArrayStack<Character> pila=new ArrayStack<Character>();
            while(!entrada.equals(null)){
            
                for(i=0;i<entrada.length();i++){
                    e=entrada.charAt(i);
                    if(Character.isDigit(e)){
                         buff.append(salida);
                         buff.append(e);
                      }
                 else
                          if(e=='(')
                              pila.push(e);
                        else        
                               if(e==')'){
                                   while(!pila.isEmpty()&&!pila.peek().equals('(')){
                                      n=pila.pop().toString();
                                      buff.append(n);
                                      buff.append("");
                                    }
                                    }              
                      if(e=='+'||e=='-'||e=='*'||e=='/'||e=='^'){
                     while(prioridad(pila.peek())>=prioridad(e)&&!pila.isEmpty()){
                            buff.append(pila.pop());
                         
                     }
                        pila.push(e); 
                           }
                      
            }
                      while(!pila.isEmpty()){
                         buff.append(pila.pop());
                      }
            
                }
                salida=buff.toString();
                return salida;
        
        
        
            }
    
    
    
        }
```

Comment: why is this tagged under javascript?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time on the page

Comment: Your `public  int  prioridad(char e)` method does nothing with `e` so there is something seriously wrong with it. All it does is scan an array and test what's in there, which is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is on this line:

```
while(prioridad(pila.peek())>=prioridad(e) && !pila.isEmpty()){
```

I think if you reverse the order of evaluation, it should fix the problem because the `&&` operator will short circuit evaulation if the first expression is false. This way it will check if the stack is not empty and only peek if it is not empty.

Try making `!pila.isEmpty()` the first operand like this:

```
while(!pila.isEmpty() && prioridad(pila.peek())>=prioridad(e)){
```